# solr indexing custom json - creates empty documents

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am quite new to solr. I currently have it running in cloud mode using docker compose (my configuration can be seen at the end of the question)

I created a collection called audittrail using default configuration. The idea is that I'll send event logging info from another app to solr. It has a convenient looking schema full of dynamic fields by default. (I know I shouldn't just use default settings in production, right now I'm looking for a proof of concept).

Now I'm following this document in an attempt to index some of my data: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#mapping-parameters

```
> curl 'http://0.0.0.0:8983/api/collections/audittrail/update/json'\
  '?split=/events&'\
  'f=action_kind_s:/action_kind_s&'\
  'f=time_dt:/events/time_dt'\
  '&echo=true' \  ########## NOTE this means we're running in debug more. solr returns the documents it should be creating
  -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
 "action_kind_s": "task_exec", 
 "events": [
     {
         "event_kind_s": "start", 
         "in_transaction_b": false, 
         "time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"
     }, 
     {
         "event_kind_s": "start_txn", 
         "in_transaction_b": true, 
         "time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"
     }, 
     {
         "event_kind_s": "diff", 
         "in_transaction_b": true, 
         "key_s": "('MerchantWorkerProcess', 5819715045818368L)", 
         "property_s": "claim_time", 
         "time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z", 
         "value_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"
     }, 
 ], 
 "final_status_s": "COMPLETE", 
 "request_s": "1dfda9955dac6f3cfd76fbedee98b15f6edc0db", 
 "task_name_s": "0p5k20100CcnMVxaxoWl32WlfPixjV1OFKgv0k1KZ0m_acc_work"
}'

# response:

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "docs":[{},
    {},
    {}]}
```

That's three empty documents...

So I thought maybe it was because I wasn't specifying an id. So I gave each event a unique id and tried again with the added `&f=id:/events/id`. Same result

Originally I tried using wildcards (`&f=/**`) with the same effect.

There is obviously something missing in my understanding.

So my question is:
What should I do to get my documents populated correctly?

EDIT

Also, my solr node logs arent turnng up any errors. Here's a sample:

```
2018-03-09 14:30:50.770 INFO  (qtp257895351-21) [c:audittrail s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [audittrail_shard2_replica_n2]  webapp=null path=/update/json params={split=/events}{add=[78953602-6b02-4948-8443-fd1ebc340921 (1594470800573857792)]} 0 3

2018-03-09 14:31:05.770 INFO  (commitScheduler-14-thread-1) [c:audittrail s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{_version_=1594470816305643520,optimize=false,openSearcher=false,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}

2018-03-09 14:31:05.770 INFO  (commitScheduler-14-thread-1) [c:audittrail s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexWriter Calling setCommitData with IW:org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter@13d117d6 commitCommandVersion:1594470816305643520

2018-03-09 14:31:05.918 INFO  (commitScheduler-14-thread-1) [c:audittrail s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.s.SolrIndexSearcher Opening [Searcher@4edc35b0[audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] realtime]

2018-03-09 14:31:05.921 INFO  (commitScheduler-14-thread-1) [c:audittrail s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:audittrail_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 end_commit_flush
```

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.11
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
    hostname: "zookeeper"
    container_name: "zookeeper"
  solr1:
    image: solr:7.2.1
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    container_name: solr1 
    links:
      - zookeeper:ZK
    command: /opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z zookeeper:2181
  solr2:
      image: solr:7.2.1
      ports:
        - "8984:8983"
      container_name: solr2
      links:
        - zookeeper:ZK
      command: /opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z zookeeper:2181
```

## Here are the exact steps I go through to index some data.

This does not actually index anything and I want to know why

1. `docker-compose up`
2. create the collection

   ```
   curl -X POST 'http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=audittrail&numShards=2'

   {
   "responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "QTime":6178},
   "success":{
   "172.24.0.3:8983_solr":{
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":3993},
     "core":"audittrail_shard1_replica_n1"},
   "172.24.0.4:8983_solr":{
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":4399},
     "core":"audittrail_shard2_replica_n2"}},
   "warning":"Using _default configset. Data driven schema functionality is enabled by default, which is NOT RECOMMENDED for production use. To turn it off: curl http://{host:port}/solr/audittrail/config -d '{\"set-user-property\": {\"update.autoCreateFields\":\"false\"}}'"}
   ```
3. curl to create some data ( this is the same curl as in the main question. but not in debug mode:

   ```
   curl 'http://0.0.0.0:8983/api/collections/audittrail/update/json?split=/events&f=action_kind_s:/action_kind_s&f=time_dt:/events/time_dt' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{ "action_kind_s": "task_exec",  "events": [{"event_kind_s": "start","in_transaction_b": false,          "time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"},{"event_kind_s": "start_txn",          "in_transaction_b": true,"time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"},{"event_kind_s": "diff", "in_transaction_b": true,"key_s": "('MerchantWorkerProcess', 5819715045818368L)","property_s": "claim_time","time_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z","value_dt": "2018-03-09T12:57:07Z"},],  "final_status_s": "COMPLETE",  "request_s": "xxx",  "task_name_s": "xxx"}'

   {
   "responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "QTime":126}}
   ```
4. Do the query:

   ```
   curl 'http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/audittrail/select?q=*:*'                                                                                                                    
   {
   "responseHeader":{
   "zkConnected":true,
   "status":0,
   "QTime":12,
   "params":{
     "q":"*:*"}},
     "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
    }}
   ```

Comment: What query is the response a response to? And are you using a schema or the schemaless mode?

Comment: @MatsLindh the `curl` right above it

Comment: But does the JSON handler return the content it indexed (I'm not sure)? What does querying the index show (i.e. a search for `*:*`)?

Comment: @MatsLindh `echo=true` so we're in debug mode

Comment: When I dont include `echo=true` then the responses are more like: `{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":17}}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's only the `echo` parameter that doesn't do what you expect it to do - remove that, and add `commit=true` to your URL to make Solr commit the documents to the index as soon as possible before returning, and you can then find documents (by searching for `*:*` in the admin interface under **collection -> query** with your fields present in the index:

```
{
  "action_kind_s":"task_exec",
  "time_dt":"2018-03-09T12:57:07Z",
  "id":"b56100f5-ff61-45e7-8d6b-8072bac6c952",
  "_version_":1594486636806144000},
{
  "action_kind_s":"task_exec",
  "time_dt":"2018-03-09T12:57:07Z",
  "id":"f49fc3cb-eac6-4d02-bcdf-b7c1a34782e3",
  "_version_":1594486636807192576}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is literally the first thing I tried. I only turned debug mode on when the data didn't show up where I was expecting it to. I've edited my question with the exact steps I'm going through from bringing up the cluster for the first time, to querying the data. Maybe I'm doing something noob (it's quite likely actually)

Comment: You're never committing (as I mentioned in my post), so searching for documents you've added before committing them to the index won't give you any results.